# Executar função a partir de uma string - JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Pessoa, bom dia!!!

Gostaria de carregar uma função em JS atraves de um JSON. É possivel?

por exemplo, faço uma solicitação na qual recebo a função em JSON

PHP: `echo json_encode(['script'=>'function Teste() {  }']);`

JS: `let func = new JSON.parse(response).script();`

Tem como eu executar "JSON.parse(response).script()" ?

Comment: Talvez você precise do [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Mas tome cuidado, é uma função perigosa, e quase nunca é recomendada ser utilizada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi na sua questão se espera que "func" seja uma função ou o valor retornado por uma função. Se for o ultimo caso pode fazer assim:

PHP

```
echo json_encode(['script'=>'let a = 1; let b=2; return a+b']);
```

JS:

```
let func = new JSON.parse(response);
let ret = Function(func.script);
```